# Any option to open custom button on a new tab

Tags: apex, visualforce

Created one Detailed page button in Account object, By clicking this button that calls a visualforce page which has a controller that makes an external HTTP call, Based on the HTTP call response we will redict the page .

The Current issue am facing is its been lauching in same page, want to open in New tab same window

Current Behavior of the button is **Display in existing window without sidebar or header**, I tried with other Behavior too no luck.

**Visual force Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="CreateOrder" action="{!getRedir}">  
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Error Messages" collapsible="false" columns="1" >
            <apex:pageMessages id="errorMessages" />
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}">&lt; Return to Account Page</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class CreateOrder {
private Boolean Failed = false;
private Integer responseCode;  
private string responseBody;
private string AtlasUserToken;
private string SalesOrderUrl;
private string auth_token;

public CreateOrder (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    Http h = new Http();
    String url ='https:/test.com/users/token';    
    //this.leadId =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');
    HttpRequest  req = buildWebServiceRequest(url);
    HttpResponse  res = invokeWebService(h,req);        
    responseCode=res.getStatusCode();
    responseBody =res.getBody().trim();  

    if (responseCode == 200){           
        Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new Map<String, Object>();
        try{
            jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>)System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        }catch(System.JSONException e){
            this.Failed =false; 
        }
        auth_token = (String)jsonMap.get('auth_token');

        Lead l = [SELECT Company,FirstName,LastName, Street, City, State, PostalCode, Phone, Email FROM Lead WHERE id=: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        SalesOrderUrl='https://test.com/salesforce/proposal?&request_for=create_order&api_call=true&address1='+l.Street + '&address2=&city='+l.City+'&state='+l.State+ '&zipcode=' + l.PostalCode + '&temp_auth_token=' +auth_token;
        this.Failed =true; 
    }else{           
        this.Failed =false;            
    }
}

public HttpRequest buildWebServiceRequest(String url) {
    //Build HTTP Request object
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);    
    gen.writeStartObject();   
    //UserInfo.getUserId();        
    User u = [select Atlas_User_Token__c from user where id=:userinfo.getuserid()];
    AtlasUserToken = u.Atlas_User_Token__c;         
    String jsonS;        
    jsonS = JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, String> {                     
            'user_token' => AtlasUserToken
                });

    // Sending the http body with JSON 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    req.setbody(jsonS); 
    System.debug(req);
    return req;
}

public HttpResponse invokeWebService(Http h, HttpRequest req) {
    //Invoke Web Service
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
    return res;        
}


public PageReference getRedir() {  
    HttpRequest  req;
    HttpResponse  res;
    if (!this.Failed) {
        // ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Sorry.  We got ' + responseCode + 'Response Code from atlas. <Br/>Current PageId==>'  + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID') +'Current UserId ==>' + UserInfo.getUserId()+ ' Atlas User Token==>' +AtlasUserToken +'  Please try again later.'));
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Sorry.  We got '+ responseCode + ' error Response from atlas. Please Contact System Administrator or try again later.'));
        return null;
    } else {       
        //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Sorry.  We got '+ auth_token + ' error Response from atlas. Please Contact System Administrator or try again later.'));
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference(SalesOrderUrl);
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;     
        //return null;           
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change visualforce or apex code.

Need to change the code behind custom button as follows to add `_parent` parameter which will open the page in new tab:

```
window.open('/apex/yourvisualforce', '_parent');
```

*Here, it is assumed that you are not trying open in a console tab*